# SQL Zero to One, or Boolean

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm currently migrating a tonne of user data from CSV spreadsheets to an SQL database, designing the schema's and all that jazz.

At this time, the Users table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    id      INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    name        VARCHAR(48) NOT NULL,
    alias       VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    email       VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,

    date_of_birth   DATE,
    location    VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,

    date_joined DATE,

    ...

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

We (the group) are looking to soon test an email subscription service for certain events and write-ups; which will be managed by looking at who is subscribed in the database.

My initial thoughts were to just add a boolean value to the Users table, representing whether they are subscribed or not, but editing the schema like this seems like a bad practice.

My second thoughts were something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Subscribers
(
    uid     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (uid)
    FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES Users(id)
);
```

What are the pro-cons of the two approaches? Which would be most suitable for my situation, given the test may be experimental.

Comment: don't use the datatype 'text' it is deprecated. Use varchar(max) use varchar(20) or whatever length is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advantages of the `Subscribers` table approach include:

- it is a higher -- actually, the highest -- normal form, being 6NF;
- it is more portable e.g. not all SQL products have a Boolean type;

There are further reasons in [this article by Joe Celko](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/bit-of-a-problem/).

The `Subscribers` table as posted has a few flaws, though. The `uid` columns should have a unique constraint. The auto-increment column is redundant. The foreign key should probably have the referential action `ON DELETE CASCADE` (and `ON UPDATE CASCADE` could prove useful in the future).

Comment: I updated my code to reflect some of the suggestions you made; not sure what you mean by ON DELETE CASCADE though; I may have to check up on that.

Comment: @Daniel: when user is deleted from the `Users` table, `ON DELETE CASCADE` would automatically delete them from the referencing table `Subscribers`. For more details see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key).

Answer (score 3):

Which course of action is suitable, depends largely on the expected use cases. If you can subscribe only to one newsletter then the boolean flag version should be preferred, since it is much faster to find the subscribers with a

```
select * from User where subscribed = 1
```

than doing a join with the possibly large `Subscribers` table. However, if you can subscribe to more than one newsletter, this would mean adding one column per newsletter to your users table (e.g `subscribedToProductAnnouncements`, `subscribedToHolidayNewsletter`, etc.). If you got a real lot of users (several millions) that might still be an option if you run into performance issues, but unless you really get performance issues using the `Subscribers` table would be preferable as you can add more newsletters without having to change the database schema all the time. That would require you to extend the `Subscribers` table with one field, though:

```
CREATE TABLE Subscribers
(
    id      LONG PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    newsletterId INTEGER NOT NULL  -- the ID of the newsletter that the user is subscribed to
    uid     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES Users(uid)
);
```

I also would go for a `LONG` in the `id` column of `Subscribers` as subscriptions may come and go and you might eventually hit the 2 billion limit of `INTEGER`. And probably renaming that table to `Subscriptions` is also a good idea as it actually contains subscriptions and not subscribers.

Comment: Nice answer, covers most of the points I was thinking about; I'll probably just go with the boolean then! Cheers.

Comment: @Daniel is there something missing in the answer, as you mentioned it covers _most_ of your points? I'd be glad to add the missing parts as well.

Comment: I think the boolean is the wrong answer. The moment you want to store data *about* the subscription and not just the *fact of* the subscription, you will suddenly regret the bit-column decision.

Answer (score 0):

well you would be better off using a Boolean... with your second thought, if a user wanted to unsubscribe you would have to delete them from the database which is a very bad idea

thats where the boolean would be better to determine if that user will allow you to send them an email

Comment: You would only delete the from the Subscribers table, not anywhere else... so your second reason doesn't make sense.

Comment: my point is you shouldn't delete from the database in any case.

Comment: Well the alternative is to alter the Users table schema; so I don't see the difference between dropping a table or dropping a column in terms of safety.

Comment: Adam "you shouldn't delete from the database in any case" is nonsense. If the *presence of a row* signifies the **same logical meaning** as the *assignment of a bit column value*, then deleting the row *has no functional difference for what the data in the database means*. Some hard rule that you "shouldn't ever delete data" is unsupportable.

Answer (score -1):

(Side note: Users doesn't have a uid column.)

Subscribers doesn't need a surrogate key. It can have just one column, which is a primary key and a foreign key on `Users(id)`.

Comment: This does not answer my question, and would better serve as a comment. Though I am interested in how you would do what you proposed (only 1 column PK FK)

Comment: Sorry, I had meant to expand my answer, but was diverted onto other matters before I got the chance.